# Can't select UI 2.8

Tags: selection-tools

So when I try to click on objects in the outline it doesn't select them

(https://gyazo.com/c6e4d591a7977941b62a1239dc4eaf76)

Also when I try to select saves it doesn't work

(https://gyazo.com/8c2445a794b4a1f69ef9a4e96c477ddd

I'm clicking on the icons and nothing is happening

Comment: I loaded factory settings and that fixed it, however I still want to know what setting I clicked to cuase this issue

Comment: Hi. Please add images inline using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post